# Define selector dynamically based on result previous selection

Tags: redux, reselect

I have selector which gets current filter type from store (filterSelector).
And 3 more, which filter entities from store using different logic, let's imagine that their names are smallEntitiesSelector, mediumEntitiesSelector, bigEntititiesSelector.

What is the best way to create selector, which will return filtered entities based on filter values in store?

```
const filteredEntities = createSelector(
    filterSelector,
    (filterType) => {
        switch filterType: 
           case "small": ???
           case "medium": ???
           case "big": ???  
    }
)
```

For this particular example I would create one selector, which accepts filter parameter, but in real case I have more complex logic inside this selectors and I don't want to mix them.

UPD: 
Due to request in comments I will add some more code. Here is a way how I make it work:

```
const filteredEntities = createSelector(
   filterSelector,
   smallEntitiesSelector,
   mediumEntitiesSelector,
   bigEntititiesSelector,
   (filterType, smallEntities, mediumEntities, bigEntities) => {
      switch filterType: 
         case "small": return smallEntities;
         case "medium": return mediumEntities;
         case "big": return bigEntities;  
   }
```

)

But I don't like this solution, because all 3 selectors will be executed every time original entities changed, while I need only one to be executed. 
So ti works, but I feel like there is a way to do it better.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour and why your solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: Expected behavior: I want to get result of one of my selectors depending on result of filterType selection.
My solution shouldn't work at all it just some kind of illustration for question.
If you put selector function instead of question marks ( smallEntitiesSelector instead of ??? for first case ) - you would get this selector as a result of filteredEntities selector, while I want to get the result of smallEntitiesSelector

Comment: It looks like a problem more related to the language then the libraries themself. Please provide your code.

Comment: I've updated post with details and example of code which is working.

Answer (score 1):

As a first attempt, you might set up 2 selectors to derive current filter and current entities data. Then, call the proper selector directly into the [result function](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc).

```
const filteredEntities = createSelector(
    filterSelector,
    entitiesSelector,   // Todo
    (filterType, entities) => {
        switch filterType: 
           case "small": return smallEntities(entities);
           case "medium": return mediumEntities(entities);
           case "big": return bigEntities(entities);
           // case default?
    }
);
```

If you step into performance/cache invalidation issues, [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect) might help you.

```
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect';

const filteredEntities = createCachedSelector(
    filterSelector,
    entitiesSelector,   // Todo
    (filterType, entities) => {
        switch filterType: 
           case "small": return smallEntities(entities);
           case "medium": return mediumEntities(entities);
           case "big": return bigEntities(entities);
           // case default?
    }
)(
    filterSelector
);
```

Comment: But will memorization will work small/medium/bigEntities selector with such implementation?

Comment: In this case cache is invalidated when `filterSelector` or `entitiesSelector` results differ from the previous call.